# extract contour levels from kdeplot in seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to extract the contours generated by kdeplot in seaborn. I was able to export the path objects using the following:

```
import numpy as np    
from seaborn import kdeplot
import random
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

lA = np.random.normal(1,0.2,1000)
ld = np.random.normal(1,0.2,1000)
kde = kdeplot(x=lA,y=ld)

lines = []
for i in kde.get_children():
    if i.__class__.__name__ == 'LineCollection':
        lines.append(i.get_paths())
```

I would like to extract the array of the contours to numpy array for further quantitative manipulation. I was able to extract something with

```
 el=lines[0].pop()
 [i for i in el.iter_segments()]
```

but I think this is not what I need, in fact I need to full contour in an array

Comment: IMO if you want to do quantitative manipulation on a kernel density estimate, the right way would be to work with the scipy tools that seaborn is using directly.

Comment: @mwaskom I considered that, I am having a hard time in finding an out-of-the-box implementation of the algorithm to compute the contours. In matplotlib it should be marching square algorithm, I know CONREC is another famous algorithm. I may consider this in the future, now I was applying this fast and furious approach. Do you think it is inherently flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is in the keyword of iter_segments that must be `simplify=False`